# I can not see the view 2

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want also call view1 and view2 methods.but it does not work.the Method "SubmitMyData" works properly and return the views for my ajax call .after run i expected the execution (for example )view2. In this example i must see view2

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("Home/SubmitMyData/")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitMyData([FromBody]MyParamModel mydata)
{             
    if (mydata.Prop1.Equals("1"))
    {
        view1();
        return View("view1");
    }
    else
    {
        view2();
        return View("view2");
    }            
}
```

here is the bodies of views methods

```
public ActionResult view1()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "view1";
    return View();
}

public ActionResult view2()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "view2";
    return View();
}
```

and here is my ajax call (if necessary to see)

```
$('#Buttonv').click(function () {
    var myData = {Prop1: "10", Prop2: ""}; 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: myData, 
        url: '/Home/SubmitMyData',          
    })
    .success(function (data) {
        $('#lblmessage').html(data);
    })
    .error(function (xhr, ajaxoption, thrownError) {
        $('#lblmessage').html("moshkelo" + xhr + "ajaxoption= " + ajaxoption + " throwerror=" + thrownError);
    })
    //return false;
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of view1() and view2() method?, its seems you are only setting ViewBag properties inside them and return statement inside view1() and view2() method will results in unreachable code for return View("view1") inside SubmitMyData method.

Comment: why not?!. it works if i enter home/view1 or home/view2 in url. I just want to call these methods in "SubmitMyData" method

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code `view2();` with `return RedirectToAction("view2");`

You need to redirect to a action than just executing it like a method.

So your code would have to like below

```
public ActionResult SubmitMyData([FromBody]MyParamModel mydata)
{             
    if (mydata.Prop1.Equals("1"))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("view1");
        //return View("view1"); // not required
    }
    else
    {
       return RedirectToAction("view2");
       // return View("view2"); // not required
    }            
}
```

Comment: But its result is the same.i receive the result in my #lblmessage in ajax call !!. i want to see the view2 (separated page).

Comment: If you are using Ajax call you will stay in the same page @amin

Comment: @amin now I got really confused, are you saying you want to show both your views ie: view 1 and view 2 after your ajax call?

Comment: No.View1 is shown if the Prop1 in mydata =1 else veiw2 is shown.Via ajax i want to manage and show the views

Comment: Oh ok... So you say after your Ajax call you want to see the result as a new page rather than spending to a div??

Comment: Yes.based on the value of Prop1 in mydata object ,i want to see the result in a new page(view1 or view2)